# How to add append Images and Footer Information with absolute positioning to all generate pages in a Itextsharp Pdf Document

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf-generation, itext, pdflib

I'm creating a pdf document with Itextsharp in VB.net and depending in the information retrieved from the database it generate a document with several pages to fit the amount of data, also I have create 2 tables in the header with some images and in the footer of the document, what I need is to append to all generated pages those  tables with the specified format.